# Is LDAP channel binding supported by PHP ldap module?

Tags: php, binding, ldap, channel

Microsoft has announced ( [ADV190023](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/ADV190023) ) that in March of this year they will be changing the default settings for AD LDAP connections to enforce Channel Binding (CBT - Channel Binding Tokens).

We use the PHP LDAP module in one of our applications to connect to AD via LDAP for user authentication and directory look ups.  Our application is hosted on both Linux/Apache Windows/IIS in case that is relevant.

**Does anyone know if channel binding is supported by PHP's LDAP module?**

If so, is there any particular version/release of PHP that is required to enable CBT support?

Comment: As far as I have been able to determine Microsoft's Channel binding uses "parameters" that are specific to Microsoft Active Directory. There is https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5056 which is a generic approach and appears to be based on  Microsoft's Implementation.

Comment: Thanks @jwilleke for your comment/feedback.  Just to clarify, my question is related specifically to Microsoft Active Directory and its use of channel binding and whether any special action needs to be taken when connecting to Microsoft Active Directory via LDAP when channel binding has been enabled, or is this something that is handled at the Windows operating system level?  My assumption was that the LDAP driver (in this case the PHP module php_ldap.dll ) would need to contain support for channel binding, but this is what I am hoping to clarify.

Comment: For your PHP app, you just must use TLS or SSL connection.

Comment: @cfales Unless Microsoft documents what type of CB is used from RFC 5929 this will remain a blackbox and impossible to implement.